# Apache Spark Jobc complete but hadoop job still running

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm running a large Spark job (about 20TB in and stored to HDFS) alongside Hadoop. The spark console is showing the job as complete but Hadoop still things the job is running, both in the console and the logs are still spitting out 'running'.

How long should I be waiting until I should be worried?

Comment: you are running spark streaming job from file system or you are running spark core

Comment: Spark Core -  the data is coming from an S3 bucket. The Spark job completed 6 hours ago but the hadoop job is still running and writing to HDFS

Answer (score 0):

You can try to stop the spark context cleanly. If you havent close it add a sparkcontext stop method at the end of the job. For example

```
sc.stop()
```